# How to set default image when imageURL is empty using SDWebImage - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sdwebimage

I have the following code at `cellForRowAt` function:

```
    let url = URL(string: myurl!)
   cell.empPhoto.image? = (cell.empPhoto.image?.circle)!
   cell.empPhoto.image? = (cell.empPhoto.image?.rounded)!

    cell.empPhoto.sd_setImage(with: url)
```

I'm using `sd_setImage` from SDWebImage to download the image from url and cache it , but sometime the url is not found or has empty content, so how to give a default image for the cell if the url is empty , should I check the content of the url before using `sd_setImage` or I can just do it from the same library ?

what I want is something like this :

```
     if url.hasImage {
       cell.empPhoto.sd_setImage(with: url)
     }
      else{ // use default image
        cell.empPhoto.image=UIImage(named: "contact")
     }
```

Comment: while setting image check length of string or check string contains expected domain name, if result false then set your expected image to image view.

Comment: @Io.s-c. Thanks , but it's not like that , all urls have the same domain but with deferent image name every employee image stored with his name , and some of them doesn't have images so here comes my problem

Comment: Is your image have any extension like png, jpeg etc.. then check if that is present in url string. simple.

Comment: @io.s-c. All urls are images url with jpeg extension , but some of these urls are not found

Comment: Ohh, So you are saying that url is correct but no image present there. in that case you can check sd image object contains image.

By using this "   if image != nil  " you can check it.

Comment: have you tried this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use this version of `sd_setImage` method:

```
cell.empPhoto.sd_setImageWithURL(url, placeholderImage:UIImage(imageNamed:"placeholder.png"))
```

*placeholderImage* will be the default image if the url does not contains a valid image.

*Additional Note:* you might want to check [Kingfisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher), it is built inspired by [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage), but is it built using Swift.

Comment: Thanks but I get error from calling this method `sd_setImageWithURL`

Comment: That depends on the version of Swift that you are using. Probably you are using Swift 3, it should be like: cell.empPhoto.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: UIImage(imageNamed:"placeholder.png"))

Answer (score 2):

It is better to have placeholder image so there will still be an image even when your request is failed.

You can set the placeholder using SDWebImage function `sd_setImageWithURL:placeholderImage`

**Swift**

```
cell.empPhoto.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: placeholderImage);
```

**Objective-C**

```
[cell.empPhoto.image sd_setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:placeholderImage];
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code too:

Swift 3 & SDWebImage 4.0.0

```
//SDWebImage 4.0.0
self.profileImageView.sd_setImage(with: yourImageUrl, placeholderImage: UIImage("Your placeholder image name")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if let imageUrl = dicData?.image, let url = URL(string: imageUrl ) {
    cell.imgMain.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "YOUR_IMAGE_NAME"), options: SDWebImageOptions.continueInBackground)
} else {
    cell.imgMain.image = UIImage(named: "YOUR_IMAGE_NAME")
}
```